# FME Layered Navigation extention in left navigation

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento 1.9.2.2

Hi all. 
I have made a Magento store with several products and categories. After this I have installed A free module to enable layered navigation to have my future customers be able to make selections on color, size etc.

Unfortunately the module does not show up in the left_info_block.

I have left the Magento standard theme as it is out of the box.

It probably is something very basic, like adding a line to local.xml but I can't figure it out.
Who is willing to help me out with this?
[image]

Comment: I do understand the policy however my question relates to configuring Magento. The module itself is not the problem. My question basically is: how to get a module visible in the left bar. Since I do not have much programmers experiance, I am stuck with some basics. Is that acceptable to keep this as "on topic". I am lost in options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all check your categories and verify that you have set your "isAnchor" flag properly.
Then check you attribute set to verify that there are some attribute with "use in layered navigation" setted up properly.

reindex all and try again

Furthermore does the magento "standard" layered navigation working ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Anchor on root category was set to "no". Have set it to "Yes". Re-indexed but the result is the same. Is there an indication on how to see if layered navigation is working? (I am new to this).

Comment: which attributes you would like to see in the layered navigation ?

Comment: The attributes: color, size and manufactor. The shop is for mans underwear. It runs in a development environment: http://oud.tothem-underwear.com/tt2015/

Comment: Problem is solved by setting Anchor to all categories in the catalog. A basic thing I did not know. Case closed.